# Trying to access state in oncompleted method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have API query and getting the result and setting those in a state variable in `Oncompleted` method of API query, Now i am updating the same state variable in another api query "onCompleted method.

I am not able to access the result from state what i have set before in first api query and below is my code

Query 1:

```
const designHubQueryOnCompleted = designHubProject => {
    if (designHubProject) {
      const {
        name,          
        spaceTypes
      } = designHubProject;
      updateState(draft => {      // setting state here 
        draft.projectName = name;          
        draft.spaceTypes = (spaceTypes || []).map(po => {
          const obj = getTargetObject(po);
          return {
            id: po.id,
            name: obj.name,
            category: obj.librarySpaceTypeCategory?.name,
            description: obj.description,
            warning: null // trying to modify this variable result in another query
          };
        });
      });
    }
  };

  const { projectDataLoading, projectDataError } = useProjectDataQuery(
    projectNumber,
    DESIGNHUB_PROJECT_SPACE_TYPES_MIN,
    ({ designHubProjects }) => designHubQueryOnCompleted(designHubProjects[0])
  );
```

Query 2:

```
   const {
    // data: designhubProjectSpaceTypeWarnings,
    loading: designhubProjectSpaceTypeWarningsLoading,
    error: designhubProjectSpaceTypeWarningsError
  } = useQuery(DESIGNHUB_PROJECT_LINKED_SPACETYPE_WARNINGS, {
    variables: {
      where: {
        projectNumber: { eq: projectNumber }
      }
    },
    onCompleted: data => {
      const projectSpaceTypeWarnings = data.designHubProjectLinkedSpaceTypeWarnings[0];
      const warnings = projectSpaceTypeWarnings.spaceTypeWarnings.reduce((acc, item) => {
        const spaceTypeIdWithWarningState = {
          spaceTypeId: item.spaceTypeProjectObjectId,
          isInWarningState: item.isInWarningState
        };
        acc.push(spaceTypeIdWithWarningState);
        return acc;
      }, []);
      console.log(state.spaceTypes); // trying to access the state here but getting empty array
      
       if (state.spaceTypes.length > 0) {           
        const updatedSpaceTypes = state.spaceTypes;
        updatedSpaceTypes.forEach(item => {
          const spaceTypeWarning = { ...item };
          spaceTypeWarning.warning = warnings?.filter(
            w => w.spaceTypeId === spaceTypeWarning.id
          ).isInWarningState;
          return spaceTypeWarning;
        });
        updateState(draft => {
          draft.spaceTypes = updatedSpaceTypes;
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Could any one please let me know where I am doing wrong with above code Or any other approach to modify the state, Many thanks in advance!!